# Как увеличить heap size для Android приложения?

Tags: android

Как увеличить heap size для Android приложения?

Comment: чего увеличить? низя вроде бы, это ограничения телефонов.. у разных моделях - разное

Comment: Размер кучи - размер в байтах блока памяти, выделенного под приложение от vm dalvik

Comment: Не конечно спасибо, но я хочу програмным способом у себя в приложении увеличить кучу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На андроидах до 3.0 увеличить хип можно только одним способом - собрать свою версию (mod). Некоторые моды позволяют менять его прямо с настроек (видел в какой то версии CyanogenMod). В версиях 3.0 и старше, можно задать в AndroidManifest.xml специальный параметр `<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:largeHeap="true" >`. На 3.0-3.1 это увеличивает хип до 256Мб. Но нужно понимать, что если хип большой, а объекты мелкие и их много, то это даст дополнительные тормоза.

Если же и этого не хватает, тогда нужно переходить на нативный код. Насколько я знаю, там допустимая память ограничена физически доступной свободной.

Если и этого не хватает, то есть последний вариант - использовать алгоритмы, которые требуют меньше памяти.

Answer (score 2):

[[APP] VM Heap Tool 2.4.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803470)

> Небольшое приложение, которое позволяет легко изменять VM размер кучи (без adb pull, edit, adb push).

Answer (score 0):

largeHeap у меня лично на тройке так и не заработал, потому есть такой хак:
[Хабра-пост](http://habrahabr.ru/post/139717/)

Лично не пробовал, но интересная штука.